# World outside Step Definition - CucumberJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumberjs

I am trying to not make connection between world/customworld and step definitions to keep it neutral.
My Hooks

```
import { Before, setWorldConstructor } from '@cucumber/cucumber';
setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld);

Before(async function (scenario) {
  this.init(scenario);
});
```

Custom World

```
import { World } from '@cucumber/cucumber';
import { Builder } from 'selenium-webdriver';

export default class extends World {
  public driver = null;
  constructor(options: any) {
    super(options);
  }
  async init(scenario: any) {
    const thisScenario = scenario;
    this.driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  }
}
```

Browser/chromedriver

```
import customWorld from './CustomWorld';

export default class driver_functions extends customWorld {

  constructor(options: any) {
    super(options);
  }

  async aa() {
    await this.driver.navigate().to('https://google.com').then((value) => {console.log(value);});
  }
}
```

I am getting errors like undefined when I call from step

```
import driver_functions from '../../utils/driver_functions';
import { Given } from '@cucumber/cucumber';
const df = new driver_functions();
Given('Home_Page: I have a simple maths calculator', async function () {
  await driver_functions.aa();
});
```

> 

```
at /Users/user.current/Projects/JS_Test/cucumber6-ts-starter-master/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/src/runtime/parallel/run_worker.ts:22:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
caused by: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'attach' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
    at new World (/Users/user.current/Projects/JS_Test/cucumber6-ts-starter-master/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/src/support_code_library_builder/world.ts:21:17)
    at new default_1 (/Users/user.current/Projects/JS_Test/cucumber6-ts-starter-master/src/utils/CustomWorld.ts:30:5)
    at new driver_functions (/Users/user.current/Projects/JS_Test/cucumber6-ts-starter-master/src/utils/driver_functions.ts:36:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user.current/Projects/JS_Test/cucumber6-ts-starter-master/src/step_definitions/maths/simple-maths-steps.ts:6:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/user.current/Projects/JS_Test/cucumber6-ts-starter-master/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1459:23)
```